# noUiSlider - limit values

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I have a slider with pips from 21 to 30 with 10 markers between the numbers (like a ruler) and I have a step size of 0.5. Is there a way to limit values, so the user cannot go under 21.5 but the marker starts from 21? I wouldn't listen to onchange, because I want to block dragging under 21.5.

Testlink: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPGgzK

```
$('#slider').noUiSlider({
    start: 21.5,
    step: 0.5,
    range: {
        'min': 21,
        'max': 31,
        '10%': 22,
        '20%': 23,
        '30%': 24,
        '40%': 25,
        '50%': 26,
        '60%': 27,
        '70%': 28,
        '80%': 29,
        '90%': 30,
        '100%': 31
    }
});

$('#slider').noUiSlider_pips({
    mode: 'range',
    density: 1
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to use the slider's [slide event](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/), for example

```
$("#slider").on({
    slide: function(){
        if ($("#slider").val() < 21.5) { // if slided to somthing less than 21.5
            $("#slider").val(21.5); // set it to 21.5
        }
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJKJaQ